# Blender 3.3 on Ubuntu 20.04, does not recognize my GPU for HIP

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, linux

My GPU (RX 5600 XT) does not appear as an option in this menu:
[image: It reads: No compatible GPUs found for Cycles. Requires AMD GPU with Vega or RDNA architecture and AMD driver version 22.10 or newer]

My card does meet those requirements and I have `Radeon™ Software for Linux® installer version 22.20 for Ubuntu 20.04.5 HWE` installed. I have a similar issue with DaVinci Resolve.

The interesting thing is that when I run blender as root, Both my GPU and CPU appear as options.

Here is some information I get from `lspci -vnn`

````
    Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT] [1682:5710]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 77
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
    Memory at fcd00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at fcd80000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu```
````

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue. After doing all of the things above, what finally worked was logging out, then restarting my device.

It probably also helped that I ran this beforehand:
`sudo usermod -a -G video username`
`sudo usermod -a -G render username`

Putting my user in the `render`/`video` group(s) seemed to give my access to GPU.